# How to detect other apps usage time & close other apps using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

#### Context

I want to create a flutter app which runs in background, whenever a certain app exceed a specific usage time it closes that app & shows the screen of flutter app (for example using instagram for 1hr, after that instagram will be closed & the flutter app will be shown)

Is there any way to detect this usage on background realtime using flutter ?